# Am I supposed to feel better if I had more time?

Tags: tenses

Did I mess up on the grammar somewhere?

Does the the first half of my sentence ("Am I supposed to...") describe a present situation, while the second half ("if we had...") not describe a present situation?

What's the correct way to phrase this sentence?

Comment: "If I/we had more time" describes a hypothetical situation. To make the two halves of the sentence fit together, you would have to say something like "Do you suppose that I would feel better if I had more time?"

Comment: Nonetheless, it is the sort of thing people often say, and I think it would go unremarked in an informal conversation, or probably also on social media.

Comment: @KateBunting So did I make a grammatical error or is it just awkward phrasing? "Do you suppose that I would feel" sounds too formal for normal conversation.

Comment: I  would expect  "Am I supposed to feel better..." to be followed by "now that X has happened?" , that is, a reference to an actual change of circumstances rather than a hypothetical one.

Comment: Please edit your question. As posted in a comment, the real question is a rhetorical one, while the tidied-up version is not. Unfortunately, the grammar fails you an instant before the rhetorical construction succeeds. Rhetoric is tricky that way.

Comment: Or: (1) *Am I supposed to **have felt** better if I had **had** more time?* (2) *Am I supposed to feel better **because** I had more time?* We don't know the context, so the question can't be answered properly. Is it describing an actual fact or something hypothetical?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Would I feel better if I had more time?' is the expression you need to sound natural.  If "supposed" is actually the meaning you want, it's a little more complex.  Then possibly "Should I feel better, if I have more time" which of course changes the tenses but sounds more natural.  If you can describe a little of the rest of the conversation or the situation, that would help a lot.

Comment: It was a political discussion. I've swapped out the political elements but it looks like I may need to include it for context. The original discussion on was when Trump said very blatantly that he left people in Iraq to take the all the oil. I interjected that conflict in the middle east is unavoidable because of the petroleum there and global superpowers want to direct the flow of it through military force. Trump's a terrible liar. I made this exact statement: "Am I supposed to feel better if we had a president who was a better liar?" Does this contain any grammatical errors?

Comment: Yes of course it was Reddit. I'm left leaning myself but the people there are rabid and just descend on each other on a hint of political deviance. Some guy said I was an idiot and grammatically incorrect, probably assuming that I supported trump.

Comment: I don't want affirmation, I just want to actually know if I made a grammatical error or not. I don't think I did but I want to check.

Comment: Compare to a simpler sentence: "The cat is sleeping if it was tired."  The problem is the mix of tenses, because the present is affected by many other things from the past (maybe the cat already took a nap).

Comment: "D'you suppose I'd feel better if..." Is that informal enough?